# Constrained optimization: first order necessary condition (Lagrange multipliers)

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Why does the first order necessary condition for constrained optimization require linear independence of the gradients of the equality constraints at the local minimum point?

Liberzon's "Calculus of Variations..." states that it is required but doesn't explain why (see section 1.2.2, p. 11 in print or p. 9 in this free online edition: http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc.pdf).

Comment: So you know why you want linear independence to get a unique solution to a linear system of equations?

Comment: Yes, and I see that linear dependence in these gradients would create non-unique Lagrange multipliers. However, I don't see why the point cannot be a local minimum in this case...

Comment: "point"?  What is the locus of solutions to $x_1 = 0, 2x_1 = 0$?  Is it a point?

Comment: So, the definition implies that a local minimum point exists, but if we cannot discriminate it form the neighbouring points then we can't call it the local minimum?

//
edit: I see that non-unique solution would produce more than a point (e.g., a line), but wouldn't each point on this line be a local minimum? I guess the uniqueness is required to define the local minimum point though... and thanks for a quick answer, it was very helpful.

Comment: No.  Suppose the solution to the equality constraints contains an entire line (or plane or larger affine subspace).  Then the minimum is either that entire line or does not exist.

Comment: ... or does not exist: "MInimize $x_1 + x_2$ subject to $x_1 = 0, 2x_1 = 0$."

Comment: Won't a minimum of your problem "MInimize 1+2 subject to 1=0,21=0." be the smallest x2 in its range, and thus possible, unless the range of x2 is a non-compact set?

Comment: I don't see any constraint on $x_2$ in that problem statement.  Consequently, one can endlessly reduce the objective by just moving further down the $x_2$-axis.  That is, the minimum fails to exist.